# Using pandas to perform regression, error: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'float' objects

Tags: python, csv, numpy, pandas, regression

I've been writing a code based on this answer ([Reading csv to array, performing linear regression on array and writing to csv in Python depending on gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36612664/reading-csv-to-array-performing-linear-regression-on-array-and-writing-to-csv-i/36612964?noredirect=1#comment60999019_36612964)) in order to find out which days exhibited an increasing wind speed in the morning.

This is a sample of my data

```
hd,Station Number,Year Month Day Hours Minutes in YYYY,MM,DD,HH24,MI format in Local time,Year Month Day Hours Minutes in YYYY,MM,DD,HH24,MI format in Local standard time,Year Month Day Hours Minutes in YYYY,MM,DD,HH24,MI format in Universal coordinated time,Precipitation since last (AWS) observation in mm,Quality of precipitation since last (AWS) observation value,Air Temperature in degrees Celsius,Quality of air temperature,Air temperature (1-minute maximum) in degrees Celsius,Quality of air temperature (1-minute maximum),Air temperature (1-minute minimum) in degrees Celsius,Quality of air temperature (1-minute minimum),Wet bulb temperature in degrees Celsius,Quality of Wet bulb temperature,Wet bulb temperature (1 minute maximum) in degrees Celsius,Quality of wet bulb temperature (1 minute maximum),Wet bulb temperature (1 minute minimum) in degrees Celsius,Quality of wet bulb temperature (1 minute minimum),Dew point temperature in degrees Celsius,Quality of dew point temperature,Dew point temperature (1-minute maximum) in degrees Celsius,Quality of Dew point Temperature (1-minute maximum),Dew point temperature (1 minute minimum) in degrees Celsius,Quality of Dew point Temperature (1 minute minimum),Relative humidity in percentage %,Quality of relative humidity,Relative humidity (1 minute maximum) in percentage %,Quality of relative humidity (1 minute maximum),Relative humidity (1 minute minimum) in percentage %,Quality of Relative humidity (1 minute minimum),Wind (1 minute) speed in km/h,Wind (1 minute) speed quality,Minimum wind speed (over 1 minute) in km/h,Minimum wind speed (over 1 minute) quality,Wind (1 minute) direction in degrees true,Wind (1 minute) direction quality,Standard deviation of wind (1 minute),Standard deviation of wind (1 minute) direction quality,Maximum wind gust (over 1 minute) in km/h,Maximum wind gust (over 1 minute) quality,Visibility (automatic - one minute data) in km,Quality of visibility (automatic - one minute data),Mean sea level pressure in hPa,Quality of mean sea level pressure,Station level pressure in hPa,Quality of station level pressure,QNH pressure in hPa,Quality of QNH pressure,#
hd, 40842,2000,03,20,10,50,2000,03,20,10,50,2000,03,20,00,50,      ,N, 25.7,N, 25.7,N, 25.6,N, 21.5,N, 21.5,N, 21.4,N, 19.2,N, 19.2,N, 19.0,N, 67,N, 68,N, 66,N, 13,N,  9,N,100,N,  4,N, 15,N,     ,N,1018.6,N,1017.5,N,1018.6,N,#
hd, 40842,2000,03,20,10,51,2000,03,20,10,51,2000,03,20,00,51,   0.0,N, 25.6,N, 25.8,N, 25.6,N, 21.5,N, 21.6,N, 21.5,N, 19.2,N, 19.4,N, 19.2,N, 68,N, 68,N, 66,N, 11,N,  9,N,107,N, 11,N, 13,N,     ,N,1018.6,N,1017.5,N,1018.6,N,#
hd, 40842,2000,03,20,10,52,2000,03,20,10,52,2000,03,20,00,52,   0.0,N, 25.8,N, 25.8,N, 25.6,N, 21.7,N, 21.7,N, 21.5,N, 19.5,N, 19.5,N, 19.2,N, 68,N, 69,N, 66,N, 11,N,  9,N, 83,N, 13,N, 13,N,     ,N,1018.6,N,1017.5,N,1018.6,N,#
hd, 40842,2000,03,20,10,53,2000,03,20,10,53,2000,03,20,00,53,   0.0,N, 25.8,N, 25.9,N, 25.8,N, 21.6,N, 21.8,N, 21.6,N, 19.3,N, 19.6,N, 19.3,N, 67,N, 68,N, 66,N,  9,N,  8,N, 87,N, 14,N, 11,N,     ,N,1018.6,N,1017.5,N,1018.6,N,#
hd, 40842,2000,03,20,10,54,2000,03,20,10,54,2000,03,20,00,54,   0.0,N, 25.8,N, 25.8,N, 25.8,N, 21.6,N, 21.6,N, 21.6,N, 19.3,N, 19.3,N, 19.2,N, 67,N, 67,N, 67,N,  8,N,  4,N, 98,N, 23,N,  9,N,     ,N,1018.6,N,1017.5,N,1018.6,N,#
hd, 40842,2000,03,20,10,55,2000,03,20,10,55,2000,03,20,00,55,   0.0,N, 25.7,N, 25.8,N, 25.7,N, 21.5,N, 21.6,N, 21.5,N, 19.2,N, 19.3,N, 19.2,N, 67,N, 68,N, 66,N,  8,N,  4,N, 68,N, 15,N,  9,N,     ,N,1018.6,N,1017.5,N,1018.6,N,#
hd, 40842,2000,03,20,10,56,2000,03,20,10,56,2000,03,20,00,56,   0.0,N, 25.9,N, 25.9,N, 25.7,N, 21.7,N, 21.7,N, 21.5,N, 19.4,N, 19.4,N, 19.2,N, 67,N, 68,N, 66,N,  8,N,  5,N, 69,N, 16,N,  9,N,     ,N,1018.6,N,1017.5,N,1018.6,N,#
hd, 40842,2000,03,20,10,57,2000,03,20,10,57,2000,03,20,00,57,   0.0,N, 26.0,N, 26.0,N, 25.9,N, 21.8,N, 21.8,N, 21.7,N, 19.5,N, 19.5,N, 19.4,N, 67,N, 68,N, 66,N,  9,N,  5,N, 72,N, 10,N, 11,N,     ,N,1018.6,N,1017.5,N,1018.6,N,#
hd, 40842,2000,03,20,10,58,2000,03,20,10,58,2000,03,20,00,58,   0.0,N, 26.0,N, 26.1,N, 26.0,N, 21.7,N, 21.8,N, 21.7,N, 19.4,N, 19.5,N, 19.3,N, 66,N, 67,N, 66,N,  8,N,  5,N, 69,N, 13,N, 11,N,     ,N,1018.6,N,1017.5,N,1018.6,N,#
```

and this is my attempted code:

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

for file in glob.glob('X:/brisbaneweatherdata/*.txt'):
    df = pd.read_csv(file)

    col = 'Wind (1 minute) speed in km/h'
    mask = pd.notnull(df[col])
    df = df.loc[mask]

    for date, group in df.groupby(['Year Month Day Hours Minutes in YYYY', 'MM', 'DD']):
        morning_data = group[group.HH24.between(9, 12)]
        gradient, intercept = np.polyfit(morning_data.HH24, morning_data['Wind (1 minute) speed in km/h'], 1)
        wind_direction = np.average(morning_data['Wind (1 minute) direction in degrees true'])
        if gradient > 0:
            print("{0:%d, %b %Y} , {1:.2f}, {2:.2f}".format(datetime(*date), gradient, wind_direction))
```

However, this is producing

```
runfile('X:/python/linearregression.py', wdir='X:/python')
X:/python/linearregression.py:1: DtypeWarning: Columns (17,25,27,29,31,33,35,37,55,57,59) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.
  import glob
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-19-ace8af14da2c>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('X:/python/linearregression.py', wdir='X:/python')

  File "C:\Users\kirkj\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 699, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\kirkj\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 74, in execfile
    exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)

  File "X:/python/linearregression.py", line 10, in <module>
    gradient, intercept = np.polyfit(morning_data.HH24, morning_data['Wind (1 minute) speed in km/h'], 1)

  File "C:\Users\kirkj\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\polynomial.py", line 550, in polyfit
    y = NX.asarray(y) + 0.0

TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'float' objects
```

If I try to convert my year values to integers of floats, e.g. `int('Year Month Day Hours Minutes in YYYY')` or `int('MM')` it produces the error `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Year Month Day Hours Minutes in YYYY'`

With help from Unutbu the TypeError issue has been resolved, however. This produces the error below.

```
runfile('X:/python/linearregression.py', wdir='X:/python')
X:/python/linearregression.py:1: DtypeWarning: Columns (17,25,27,29,31,33,35,37,55,57,59) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.
  import glob
C:\Users\kirkj\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\polynomial.py:594: RankWarning: Polyfit may be poorly conditioned
  warnings.warn(msg, RankWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-24-ace8af14da2c>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('X:/python/linearregression.py', wdir='X:/python')

  File "C:\Users\kirkj\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 699, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\kirkj\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 74, in execfile
    exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)

  File "X:/python/linearregression.py", line 17, in <module>
    wind_direction = np.average(morning_data['Wind (1 minute) direction in degrees true'])

  File "C:\Users\kirkj\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 570, in average
    avg = a.mean(axis)

  File "C:\Users\kirkj\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py", line 72, in _mean
    ret = ret / rcount

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'
```

Comment: Can you include the full `TypeError` message, including the traceback that shows where the problem happened?

Comment: I have included the full error message in the question now.

Comment: I suspect this has to do with how the column headers were parsed.  Where did you source the data? You may want to try parsing the data itself without the column names. `df = pd.read_csv(file, header=None)`

Comment: If I parse that data without the column names, what do I use to group the columns into dates for the command                 'for date, group in df.groupby(['Year Month Day Hours Minutes in YYYY','MM','DD']):'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message

```
  File "C:\Users\kirkj\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\polynomial.py", line 550, in polyfit
    y = NX.asarray(y) + 0.0

TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'float' objects
```

can be reproduced if `y` is a Series containing a string:

```
In [14]: np.asarray(pd.Series(['',1.0])) + 0.0
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'float' objects
```

Now if you [peek at line 550 inside `polynomial.py`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/lib/polynomial.py#L551), you'll see that `y` is the second argument passed to `np.polyfit`. So this suggests strongly that `morning_data['Wind (1 minute) speed in km/h']` is a Series containing a string.

The sample data that you posted does not show a string, but somewhere further along in the CSV you'll likely find a string in that column.

Now how can we find that string? One way would be to convert the Series to numeric values (coercing invalid strings to NaN):

```
col = 'Wind (1 minute) speed in km/h'
tmp = pd.to_numeric(morning_data[col], errors='coerce')
```

and then to look for NaN:

```
mask = pd.isnull(tmp)
print(morning_data.loc[mask, col])
```

This will show you all the values in the `'Wind (1 minute) speed in km/h'` column which could not be converted to numerals.

You could then consider how you wish to handle these problematic rows.  If there
are just a few of them, you might edit them by hand. Or look into how the CSV
was generated and fix the error at the source. Or, if you want to discard these
rows, you could use

```
for file in glob.glob('X:/brisbaneweatherdata/*.txt'):
    df = pd.read_csv(file)

    for col in ['Wind (1 minute) speed in km/h', 
                'Wind (1 minute) direction in degrees true']:
        df[col] = pd.to_numeric(df[col], errors='coerce')
        mask = pd.notnull(df[col])
        df = df.loc[mask]

    for date, group in df.groupby(['Year Month Day Hours Minutes in YYYY', 'MM', 'DD']):
        morning_data = group[group.HH24.between(9, 12)]
        if len(morning_data) == 0: continue
        gradient, intercept = np.polyfit(morning_data['HH24'], morning_data['Wind (1 minute) speed in km/h'], 1)
        wind_direction = np.average(morning_data['Wind (1 minute) direction in degrees true'])
        if gradient > 0:
            print("{0:%d, %b %Y} , {1:.2f}, {2:.2f}".format(datetime(*date), gradient, wind_direction))
```

and then the rest of the code should have a chance of working.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Using the code in the question, and your code (which i have edited the question to include) I am recieving the same TypeError message, suggesting that the polyfit is still struggling.

Comment: @JossKirk: I had forgotten to add `df[col] = pd.to_numeric(df[col], errors='coerce')` -- you'll see it if you refresh the web page. Without it, `df[col]` still contains numeric strings. Hence the `TypeError`.

Comment: Thanks! That seems to have resolved that issue. I have updated the question to include the new TypeError that is occurring. This time it is the Wind direction that is being troublesome. Would that also be resolvable through data coercion?

Comment: Since the error message mentions `str` it is probably due the same kind of problem. I've update the code to apply the same fix to the `'Wind (1 minute) direction in degrees true'` column. Be sure to investigate what values you are discarding!

Comment: Thanks so much for you help. That seems to have resolved the issue. Perusing the data there are quite a few rows in which there is no data (presumably because the weather station malfunction for that time period) so it is likely those rows I am discarding. Thanks again!

Comment: Final question. This works well for most files until about 36 months in it gives the error TypeError("expected non-empty vector for x) with regards to the wind speed it seems. Perusing the data, there are many missing days for that particular date. Will this type of data coercion cease to work if there are too many missing rows? Ultimately I will probably skip that particular day, just asking out of curiosity.

Comment: You could use `if len(morning_data) == 0: continue` to skip groups with no `morning_data`. I've edited the post above to show what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

I adjusted `.between('9', '12')` to `.between(9, 12)`, the `np.average` calculation to only use `morning_data['Wind (1 minute) direction in degrees true']`, and added `string` formatting to the final `print` statement:

```
from datetime import datetime
for date, group in df.groupby(['Year Month Day Hours Minutes in YYYY', 'MM', 'DD']):
    morning_data = group[group.HH24.between(9, 12)]
    gradient, intercept = np.polyfit(morning_data.HH24, morning_data['Wind (1 minute) speed in km/h'], 1)
    wind_direction = np.average(morning_data['Wind (1 minute) direction in degrees true'])
    if gradient > 0:
        print("{0:%d, %b %Y} , {1:.2f}, {2:.2f}".format(datetime(*date), gradient, wind_direction))
```

which ends up working fine (at least without errors), producing:

```
20, Mar 2000 , 0.47, 83.67
```

This is the `DataFrame` I'm getting after copying your sample:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 9 entries, 0 to 8
Data columns (total 62 columns):
hd                                                             9 non-null object
Station Number                                                 9 non-null int64
Year Month Day Hours Minutes in YYYY                           9 non-null int64
MM                                                             9 non-null int64
DD                                                             9 non-null int64
HH24                                                           9 non-null int64
MI format in Local time                                        9 non-null int64
Year Month Day Hours Minutes in YYYY.1                         9 non-null int64
MM.1                                                           9 non-null int64
DD.1                                                           9 non-null int64
HH24.1                                                         9 non-null int64
MI format in Local standard time                               9 non-null int64
Year Month Day Hours Minutes in YYYY.2                         9 non-null int64
MM.2                                                           9 non-null int64
DD.2                                                           9 non-null int64
HH24.2                                                         9 non-null int64
MI format in Universal coordinated time                        9 non-null int64
Precipitation since last (AWS) observation in mm               9 non-null object
Quality of precipitation since last (AWS) observation value    9 non-null object
Air Temperature in degrees Celsius                             9 non-null float64
Quality of air temperature                                     9 non-null object
Air temperature (1-minute maximum) in degrees Celsius          9 non-null float64
Quality of air temperature (1-minute maximum)                  9 non-null object
Air temperature (1-minute minimum) in degrees Celsius          9 non-null float64
Quality of air temperature (1-minute minimum)                  9 non-null object
Wet bulb temperature in degrees Celsius                        9 non-null float64
Quality of Wet bulb temperature                                9 non-null object
Wet bulb temperature (1 minute maximum) in degrees Celsius     9 non-null float64
Quality of wet bulb temperature (1 minute maximum)             9 non-null object
Wet bulb temperature (1 minute minimum) in degrees Celsius     9 non-null float64
Quality of wet bulb temperature (1 minute minimum)             9 non-null object
Dew point temperature in degrees Celsius                       9 non-null float64
Quality of dew point temperature                               9 non-null object
Dew point temperature (1-minute maximum) in degrees Celsius    9 non-null float64
Quality of Dew point Temperature (1-minute maximum)            9 non-null object
Dew point temperature (1 minute minimum) in degrees Celsius    9 non-null float64
Quality of Dew point Temperature (1 minute minimum)            9 non-null object
Relative humidity in percentage %                              9 non-null int64
Quality of relative humidity                                   9 non-null object
Relative humidity (1 minute maximum) in percentage %           9 non-null int64
Quality of relative humidity (1 minute maximum)                9 non-null object
Relative humidity (1 minute minimum) in percentage %           9 non-null int64
Quality of Relative humidity (1 minute minimum)                9 non-null object
Wind (1 minute) speed in km/h                                  9 non-null int64
Wind (1 minute) speed quality                                  9 non-null object
Minimum wind speed (over 1 minute) in km/h                     9 non-null int64
Minimum wind speed (over 1 minute) quality                     9 non-null object
Wind (1 minute) direction in degrees true                      9 non-null int64
Wind (1 minute) direction quality                              9 non-null object
Standard deviation of wind (1 minute)                          9 non-null int64
Standard deviation of wind (1 minute) direction quality        9 non-null object
Maximum wind gust (over 1 minute) in km/h                      9 non-null int64
Maximum wind gust (over 1 minute) quality                      9 non-null object
Visibility (automatic - one minute data) in km                 9 non-null object
Quality of visibility (automatic - one minute data)            9 non-null object
Mean sea level pressure in hPa                                 9 non-null float64
Quality of mean sea level pressure                             9 non-null object
Station level pressure in hPa                                  9 non-null float64
Quality of station level pressure                              9 non-null object
QNH pressure in hPa                                            9 non-null float64
Quality of QNH pressure                                        9 non-null object
#                                                              9 non-null object
dtypes: float64(12), int64(24), object(26)
memory usage: 4.4+ KB
```

Comment: I have used your code, provided here, and have imported datetime. But it still produces the same type error. I have updated the question to include the new code and the new error message. And if I make wind direction column float it also produces a type error.

Comment: Needed  to `from datetime import datetime`, see update, also included what the data look like.

Comment: Thanks for your help, TypeError is still occurring, will have to keep working on it.

Comment: As you can see, I am not getting an error because the data sample does only contain numeric values for the `Wind...` variable. Just fix the data type by coercing and you'll be fine. But also keep the various other adjustments I suggested.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. Noob error. I am having problems now with the wind direction variable, but perhaps coercing that variable should resolve that issue as well.

Comment: 2 suggestions: simplify your variable names, and always look at `df.info()` so you can see right away if a data type is off for what you are planning to do, like `string` (`object` in `pandas`) for a regression, etc

Comment: Good advice. I will have to figure out why the dataframe is interpreting the wind direction as an object. Thanks for your help!

Comment: take a look at `.value_counts()` or `.describe()` for that column.